# Why is F# Expression tree generation is much slower than C#, can it be made faster?

Tags: c#, f#, expression

Building a simple expression tree in F#:

```
type Quote<'T> = 
    static member X(exp:Expression<Func<'T,'a>>) = exp

type T = { x:int }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    for _ in [1..4] do
        let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        [for i in [1..10000] -> Quote.X(fun x -> x.x = i)] |> ignore
        printfn "Elapsed: %A" sw.Elapsed
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

On both .NET and mono is about **x35** slower than this C#:

```
class Program
{
    class T {public int x {get;set;}}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Enumerable.Range(0,10000)
                .Select(i => (Expression<Func<T,bool>>)(t => t.x == i ))
                .ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("Ellapsed: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows why that is and if there's something I could do to improve it?
The solution is on github in case someone wants to try: https://github.com/et1975/ExpressionTrees

Comment: Think the C# compiler is smart enough to eliminate the whole loop as the result is not used. Can you see how much they differ when you also sum up the range and output that number to the commandline?

Comment: @gjvdkamp Compiled IL of that C# code doesn't look as it does nothing.

Comment: @ Eugene These pieces are not equivalent as they seems. F# uses `Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr` inside and C# uses `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`.

Comment: Are you just curious, or do you have an actual scenario where the performance of creating quotations in F# is a problem for you?

Comment: What about the list comprehension in F# vs `Enumerable.Range` in C#? Perhaps most of the computation goes to creating the list data structure, not the actual `Expression` objects?

Comment: `for _ in [1..4]` and `for i in [1..10000]` should not use list comprehensions, but be just a for loop. `for i = 1 to 4` and `for i = 1 to 10000`. If you want to use a `seq` in the inner loop, the syntax is `for i = 1..10000` without creating an intermediate list. That said, this is definitely not the *x35* speed-up.

Comment: @kvb, it's both. I was profiling my rest api that was executing queries and the expression tree generation was red-flagged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Linq.Expressions.Expression in F#, but it looks ugly:

```
open System.Linq.Expressions

let paramExpr:ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter( typedefof<int>, "asd")

let pList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ParameterExpression>()
pList.Add(paramExpr)

// This expression represents a lambda expression 
// that adds 1 to the parameter value.
let lambdaExpr:LambdaExpression = 
    Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Add(paramExpr, Expression.Constant(1)), pList)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    for _ in [1..4] do
        let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        [for i in [1..10000] -> lambdaExpr] |> ignore
        printfn "Elapsed: %A" sw.Elapsed
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Actually, no. Look closely: F# version uses `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`, too. The F# quotation type is called `Expr`, not `Expression`, and its generic parameter is F# function, not .NET delegate.

Comment: If you look at IL of Eugene F# code you can see there is F#'s `LeafExpressionConverter` converting `fun` to `System.Func<...+T,System.Boolean>` and the only usage of `Linq.Espressions` is `call        Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<...+T,System.Boolean>>>..ctor`